# Sending more than three letters of recommendation to neuroscience PhD application

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I am currently a rising undergraduate senior who plans to attend graduate school after I finish this last year. I want to work toward a PhD in neuroscience.

I know this question is commonly asked, but at this point I feel like it's important for me to get input on my personalized situation.

Many of the schools I'm applying to take three or more recommendation letters, often up to five or six. I've had three research experiences (two summer internships plus undergraduate research), so those are my three core reference letters.

This is where my main point comes in: I have been debating about adding a fourth letter from a professor for whom I have taught a weekly chemistry workshop class since freshman year and TAed/proctored for other aspects of his chemistry courses as well as a fifth letter from a professor who is my senior thesis adviser/reader (with whom I also took a graduate course where a large part was based on proposing new experiments in the form of specific aims papers). Essentially, I feel that these additional reference writers (with whom I am in good contact) would only add to my application, but I don't want to overdo it. What are your opinions on adding these letter writers that, to me, speak on different parts of my ability to act as a graduate student and beyond (in contrast to my three research PIs)?

Note that by no means am I trying to “fill the gaps” and reach the highest number of possible reference letters. If I were to do that, I could easily ask for six letters. But I'm approaching it more strategically – I will make sure to only include effective letters that speak diversely on my ability to conduct research and act as a graduate student/young scientist.